# How to check IEnumerable<DataRow> returns null or has any row?

Tags: c#, linq

i have a linq query similar like below.

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query= (from item in IItemsTable.AsEnumerable()
                         where somecondition
                         select item);
```

how to check query contains any row or is empty?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the extension method [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx):

```
if(query.Any())
{
    //query has results.
}
```

---

Note that if you only care whether there are rows or not (and don't subsequently do something with those rows) you can use another overload of `Any()` to do it in one line:

```
bool queryhasresults = IItemsTable.AsEnumerable().Any(item => somecondition);
```

Comment: No need to say thank you, accepting the answer and/or upvoting is your way of saying thanks.

Comment: No problem, i'm just saying you don't need to say thanks even if you can't accept yet. :)

Comment: +1 because you didn't recommend query.Count>0. Any() is much more performant over large datasets/object collections/databases than Count > 1.

Comment: You will need the using statement `using System.Linq` if you don't have it already