# How do I check for an empty IEnumerable<DataRow> collection?

Tags: c#, linq

According to the answer given for the same question: [How to check IEnumerable<DataRow> returns null or has any row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203512/how-to-check-ienumerabledatarow-returns-null-or-has-any-row) and most of the google results I found, you are suppose to use .Any() to verify that the collection contains at least one item.

However, in the following code the .Any() is throwing an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception.  Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
DataSet navData = GetNavigationData();
bool linkFound = false;

if(!CommonLibrary.IsDataSetEmpty(navData))
{
  IEnumerable<DataRow> foundLinks = from link in navData.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                    where link.Field<string>("URL").ToLower() == searchURL
                                    select link;

  linkFound = (foundLinks.Any());
}
```

The relevant stack trace showing that the exception is coming from the Any() call:

```
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at MyMethod in MySource.cs:line 259
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the parentheses around the `Any()` call?

Comment: @bolt: boolean voodoo. It's actually short for `(false != x.Any())`

Comment: What's the type of exception?

Comment: And the _full_ stacktrace might be interesting as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not that `Any()` is the problem.  Your problem is that a field you are trying to access in your query is most likely returning `null`.

I'd check that navData is not `null` and Tables is not `null` and `Tables[0]` is not null.  Any() uses deferred execution, so when you assign your query it won't necessarily get processed until it is requested, which happens to be when `Any()` is called.  Thus any problems with the query will not manifest until it is actually iterated over.

Comment: Yes, start at the beginning. I wouldn't rule out a ConnectionString problem.

Comment: Okay, why the downvote?  If you're going to downvote at least say why.

Comment: @Henk: Why is that, where did everyone run off to?

Comment: 2 answers claiming that `link` could be null, but it can't.

Comment: I went ahead and marked this as the answer as it helped me pinpoint where the null exception was coming from.  In the end, the culprit was the .ToLower() call that I originally left out of my sample code.  Basically, changing the where clause to the following eliminates the exception; although, I don't like pulling the field's value twice :S

`where (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(link.Field<string>("URL") && link.Field<string>("URL").ToLower() == searchURL)`