# LINQ query IEnumerable<Object> for IEnumerable<DataRow> results in null

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

**Why is my LINQ query ("rows") showing up as a null when it seems like I have plenty of data ("waypoints")?**

I'm doing an insert of ~20k records and rather than go through Entity Framework I've opted for SqlBulkCopy, which seems to mean I need a datatable. I'm trying to get an IEnumerable into IEnumberable as that seems to be the only way to get CopyToDataTable().

I was copying the syntax [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203512/how-to-check-ienumerabledatarow-returns-null-or-has-any-row), and you can see in my debugger that I have plenty of objects in my original list but IEnumerable is null.

[image]

Same code, maybe easier to read:

```
    IEnumerable<DataRow> rows =
            (from w in waypoints.AsEnumerable()
            select w)  as IEnumerable<DataRow>;

    DataTable table = rows.CopyToDataTable();
```

The "rows" variable is returning as null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to typecase an `IEnumerable<Waypoint>` as an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, which is not going to work unless your `Waypoint` class is derived from `DataRow`, which I assume it's not. The [documentation for the `CopyToDataTable` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is pretty clear:

> The parameter T of the input parameter source can only be of type DataRow or a type derived from DataRow.

You are going to have to make your data table the long way, unfortunately. Make a new blank `DataTable`, add columns to it's `Columns` collection, then add rows to it's `Rows` collection.

Comment: thanks michael. sometimes i have to remind myself that if this stuff was easy we'd all be unemployed.